# Different text but same CRC checksum?

Tags: java, crc32

My application use CRC32 to check two contents or two files are same or not.
But when I try it use to generate unique id, I see the problem, with the two different string, the CRC32 can be same. Here is my Java code. Thanks in advance.

```
public static String getCRC32(String content) {
    byte[] bytes = content.getBytes();
    Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
    checksum.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);            
    return String.valueOf(checksum.getValue());
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(getCRC32("b5a7b602ab754d7ab30fb42c4fb28d82"));
    System.out.println(getCRC32("d19f2e9e82d14b96be4fa12b8a27ee9f"));       
}
```

Comment: Hash codes or CRC checksums are not unique IDs. They can't be - see [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that's what CRCs are like. They're *not* unique IDs. They're *likely* to be different for different inputs, but they don't *have* to be. After all, you're providing more than 32 bits of input, so you can't expect to have more than 2<sup>32</sup> different inputs to all produce different CRCs.

A longer cryptographic hash (e.g. SHA-256) is far *more likely* to give different outputs for different inputs, but it's still not impossible (and can't be, due to the amount of input data vs output data). The big difference between a CRC and a cryptographic hash is that a CRC is relatively easy to "steer" if you want to - it's not terribly hard to find collisions, and it's used to protect against *accidental* data corruption. Cryptographic hashes are designed to protect against *deliberate* data corruption by some attacker - so it's hard to deliberately create a value targeting a specific hash.

As an aside, your use of `String.getBytes()` without specifying a charset is problematic - it uses the platform-default encoding, so if you run the same code on two machines with the same input, you can get different results. I would strongly encourage you to use a fixed encoding (e.g. UTF-8).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they can be the same, but that will occur accidentally with a very low probability of 2<sup>-32</sup>.

As Jon noted, you can construct strings with the same CRC deliberately.  [My spoof code](https://github.com/madler/spoof) automates that.  Here is an example of another string with the same CRC as those presented in the problem, but with limited differences from the first string: `b5a7b702ab643f7ac47fb57c4fb28b82`, generated using spoof.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal to find 2 different files/strings/data with same CRC32. There are only 32 bits. Use MD5/SHA1-512 to be more protected from duplication.